# xpath copied from inspector returns wrong results

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm using selenium webdriver configured with chrome and want to scrape the price from Yahoo Finance.  An example page is: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/0001.KL

I've opened the example page in a chrome browser and used the inspector to navigate to where the price is highlighted on the page and use the inspector's copy xpath for use in my python script. 
[image]

```
import os
from lxml import html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ua = UserAgent()

def yahoo_scrape_one(kl_stock_id):
    ''' function to scrape yahoo finance for a single KLSE stock returns dict'''        
    user_agent = ua.random
    chrome_driver = os.getcwd() + '/chromedriver'
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('user-agent={user_agent}')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options,
                      executable_path=chrome_driver)
    prefix = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'
    suffix = '.KL'
    url = prefix + kl_stock_id + suffix
    driver.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
    price = tree.xpath('//*[@id="quote-header-info"]/div[3]/div/div/span[1]/text()')
    print(price)

test_stock = "0001"
yahoo_scrape_one(test_stock)
```

the print output is

```
['+0.01 (+1.41%)']
```

This appears to be information from the next span (change and percent change) not the price. Any insights on this curious behaviour would be appreciated. Any suggestions on an alternate approach would also give joy.

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem. I get `['0.36']` as output when using the same XPath.

Comment: @MihaiChelaru I've updated my code snip to include the imports but I'm still not getting the price :  ['0.36']   are you using selenium's  html.fromstring method?

Comment: if you're having problems can't you just get all text from the parent div then remove everything after the first line of text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running your actual script, I got the same "erroneous" output you were reporting. However, I then commented out the headless option and ran the driver again, inspecting the element within the actual Selenium browser instance, and found that the XPath for the element is different on the page generated by your script. Use the following line of code instead:

```
price = tree.xpath('//*[@id="quote-header-info"]/div[3]/div/span/text()')
```

This produces the correct output of `['0.36']`

Comment: Ok that worked thank you.  My takeaway from this experience is:
XPath copy from the inspector gets you in the neighbourhood but can give erroneous results.  If the first span instance in a div is desired  use .../div/span/text() 
but to get the second instance,  use 
.../div./span[1]/text()

Answer (score 0):

This is another way you can achieve the same output without hardcoding index:

```
price = tree.xpath("//*[@id='quote-market-notice']/../span")[0].text
```